# nth-child doesn't apply to first two child elements

Tags: html, css

Hello guys here is a simple calendar. At the bottom, in last row, last 4 days are days of next month, so that i want to make them none background.
. They have a class: next-month and i make nth-child so:

```
#Januar .next-month:nth-child(-n + 2){
    background:none!important
}
```

. and with that i apply backgrounds to all elements:

```
.calendar tbody td:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opeoep. Why doesn't it hides background? :nth-child(-n + 2) means first two elements, is not?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

.prev-month,
.next-month {
  color: #cacaca
}

#Januar .next-month:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  background: none!important
}

#active {
  color: #F45537 !important;
  font-weight: 900;
}

td {
  padding: 0
}

.Januar {
  font: 87.5%/1.5em Lato, sans-serif;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.calendar-container {
  position: relative
}

.calendar-container header {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: #e66b6b;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center
}

.tooltiptext {
  display: none;
}

.tooltiptext {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1
}

.newyear .tooltiptext {
  top: 70px;
  left: 61px;
}

.sixjanuar .tooltiptext {
  top: 70px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.newyear:hover .tooltiptext,
.sixjanuar:hover .tooltiptext {
  display: inline-block
}

.newyear:hover,
.sixjanuar:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

.month {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}

.weeks {
  font-size: 10px!important
}

.weeks:hover {
  background: none!important
}

.calendar {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px
}

.calendar thead {
  color: #e66b6b;
  font-weight: 500
}

.calendar td {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}

tr td:first-child {
  font-size: 11px!important
}

.calendar tbody td:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

.calendar tbody td:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  background: #d5e6ff
}

.current-day {
  color: #e66b6b;
  background: #cacaca;
  font-weight: bolder
}
```

```html
<table id="Januar" class="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Mo</td>
      <td>Di</td>
      <td>Mi</td>
      <td>Do</td>
      <td>Fr</td>
      <td>Sa</td>
      <td>So</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">01</td>
      <td id="active" class="newyear">1<span class="tooltiptext">Neujahr<br>01.01.2018<br>gesetzlicher Feiertage</span></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td id="active" class="sixjanuar">6<span class="tooltiptext">Heilige Drei Könige<br>06.01.2018<br>gesetzlicher Feiertag in Baden-Württemberg, Bayern, Sachsen-Anhalt</span></td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">02</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">03</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">04</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">05</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td class="next-month">1</td>
      <td class="next-month">2</td>
      <td class="next-month">3</td>
      <td class="next-month">4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try this style `.prev-month, .next-month {
    color: #cacaca;
    background: #fff !important;
}` i thing its working

Answer (score 0):

I applied `background: none` to 7th and 8th `.next-month`. I hope i will work for you.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

.prev-month,
.next-month {
  color: #cacaca
}

#Januar .next-month:nth-child(7),
#Januar .next-month:nth-child(8){
  background: none!important
}

#Januar .next-month:hover{
  background: none!important
}

#active {
  color: #F45537 !important;
  font-weight: 900;
}

td {
  padding: 0
}

.Januar {
  font: 87.5%/1.5em Lato, sans-serif;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.calendar-container {
  position: relative
}

.calendar-container header {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: #e66b6b;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center
}

.tooltiptext {
  display: none;
}

.tooltiptext {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1
}

.newyear .tooltiptext {
  top: 70px;
  left: 61px;
}

.sixjanuar .tooltiptext {
  top: 70px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.newyear:hover .tooltiptext,
.sixjanuar:hover .tooltiptext {
  display: inline-block
}

.newyear:hover,
.sixjanuar:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

.month {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}

.weeks {
  font-size: 10px!important
}

.weeks:hover {
  background: none!important
}

.calendar {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px
}

.calendar thead {
  color: #e66b6b;
  font-weight: 500
}

.calendar td {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}

tr td:first-child {
  font-size: 11px!important
}

.calendar tbody td:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

.calendar tbody td:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  background: #d5e6ff
}

.current-day {
  color: #e66b6b;
  background: #cacaca;
  font-weight: bolder
}
```

```html
<table id="Januar" class="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Mo</td>
      <td>Di</td>
      <td>Mi</td>
      <td>Do</td>
      <td>Fr</td>
      <td>Sa</td>
      <td>So</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">01</td>
      <td id="active" class="newyear">1<span class="tooltiptext">Neujahr<br>01.01.2018<br>gesetzlicher Feiertage</span></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td id="active" class="sixjanuar">6<span class="tooltiptext">Heilige Drei Könige<br>06.01.2018<br>gesetzlicher Feiertag in Baden-Württemberg, Bayern, Sachsen-Anhalt</span></td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">02</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">03</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">04</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">05</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td class="next-month">1</td>
      <td class="next-month">2</td>
      <td class="next-month">3</td>
      <td class="next-month">4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't hide backgrounds :(

Comment: By background, you mean the blue color of "3,4" in last row, right?

Comment: not, gray backgroudn of last "1,2" . i need two hide backgrounds only these numbers.

Comment: You mean the grey color on :hover??

Comment: Yes, grey background color

Answer (score 0):

The following selectors: `#Januar .next-month:nth-child(-n + 2)` will only apply if there are no other `td` (table cell) elements *preceding* the elements with the class `.next-month`.

So, in this case, the aforementioned selectors are essentially reading: "select elements with the class `.next-month` **if** they are the *first two elements* nested within a containing element".

Consider counting from the *bottom of the source order*, and not the top, e.g:

```
#Januar tr .next-month:nth-last-child(n+3) {
    background: none;
}
```

*No need for the `!important` declaration. The structural pseudo-class selector (`nth-last-child`) adds enough specificity, and the `id` selector used attributes more than enough **weight** as well*

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

.prev-month,
.next-month {
  color: #cacaca
}

#Januar tr .next-month:nth-last-child(n+3) {
  background: none;
}

#active {
  color: #F45537 !important;
  font-weight: 900;
}

td {
  padding: 0
}

.Januar {
  font: 87.5%/1.5em Lato, sans-serif;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.calendar-container {
  position: relative
}

.calendar-container header {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: #e66b6b;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center
}

.tooltiptext {
  display: none;
}

.tooltiptext {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1
}

.newyear .tooltiptext {
  top: 70px;
  left: 61px;
}

.sixjanuar .tooltiptext {
  top: 70px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.newyear:hover .tooltiptext,
.sixjanuar:hover .tooltiptext {
  display: inline-block
}

.newyear:hover,
.sixjanuar:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

.month {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}

.weeks {
  font-size: 10px!important
}

.weeks:hover {
  background: none!important
}

.calendar {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 3px 1px #fff;
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px
}

.calendar thead {
  color: #e66b6b;
  font-weight: 500
}

.calendar td {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}

tr td:first-child {
  font-size: 11px!important
}

.calendar tbody td:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

.calendar tbody td:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  background: #d5e6ff
}

.current-day {
  color: #e66b6b;
  background: #cacaca;
  font-weight: bolder
}
```

```html
<table id="Januar" class="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Mo</td>
      <td>Di</td>
      <td>Mi</td>
      <td>Do</td>
      <td>Fr</td>
      <td>Sa</td>
      <td>So</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">01</td>
      <td id="active" class="newyear">1<span class="tooltiptext">Neujahr<br>01.01.2018<br>gesetzlicher Feiertage</span></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td id="active" class="sixjanuar">6<span class="tooltiptext">Heilige Drei Könige<br>06.01.2018<br>gesetzlicher Feiertag in Baden-Württemberg, Bayern, Sachsen-Anhalt</span></td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">02</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">03</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">04</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="weeks">05</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td class="next-month">1</td>
      <td class="next-month">2</td>
      <td class="next-month">3</td>
      <td class="next-month">4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```